# my custom arraylist it keeps crashing everytime it boots up am unsure why it keeps crashing

Tags: java, android

My code keeps crashing am not really sure whats wrong all i know is that the caller for the arraylist is not receiving it I feel as though its something with the adapter. there is no exception in android studio sinces it lets the app run the app opens up it crashes. heres what the debugger says. the app runs until the return line within the arraylist after that the app crashes.

> ```
>  E/e.reportcardap: Invalid ID 0x00000041.
>  D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.reportcardapp, PID: 8949
> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x41
>     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:348)
>     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5858)
>     at com.example.reportcardapp.ReportCardAdapter.getView(ReportCardAdapter.java:45)
>     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2373)
>     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2052)
>     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:786)
>     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:847)
>     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1826)
>     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2165)
>     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20713)
>     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6197)
>     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20713)
>     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6197)
>     at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
>     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20713)
>     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6197)
>     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20713)
>     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6197)
>     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
>     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
>     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
>     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20713)
>     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6197)
>     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:792)
>     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20713)
>     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6197)
>     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2831)
>     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2358)
>     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1494)
>     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7288)
>     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
>     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
>     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
>     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6936)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>     at     com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
> ```

//Main activity //

```
package com.example.reportcardapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grade_list);


    ArrayList<Grade> grades = new ArrayList<Grade>();


    grades.add(new Grade("Name: Jake;", "Math;", 'A'));
    grades.add(new Grade("Name: Jake;", "Science", 'C'));
    grades.add(new Grade("Name: Jake;", "Gym", 'B'));
    grades.add(new Grade("Name: Jake;", "Web Design", 'c'));
    grades.add(new Grade("Name: Jake;", "Music", 'F'));

    ReportCardAdapter aadapter = new ReportCardAdapter(this, grades);

    // Find the {@link ListView} object in the view hierarchy of the {@link Activity}.
    // There should be a {@link ListView} with the view ID called list, which is declared in the
    // word_list.xml layout file.
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Make the {@link ListView} use the {@link WordAdapter} we created above, so that the
    // {@link ListView} will display list items for each {@link Word} in the list.
    listView.setAdapter(aadapter);

}

}
```

// Grade class
    package com.example.reportcardapp;

```
public class Grade {
private String mname;
private String mclassName;
private char mgradeLetter;


public Grade(String name, String className, char gradeLetter) {
    mname = name;
    mclassName = className;
    mgradeLetter = gradeLetter;
}

public String getName() {
    return mname;
}

public String getClassName() {
    return mclassName;
}

public char getGradeLetter() {
    return mgradeLetter;
}
}
```

//Report Card addapter//

```
package com.example.reportcardapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


import java.util.ArrayList;


 public class ReportCardAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Grade> {


public ReportCardAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Grade> grades) {
    super(context, 0, grades);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)        {
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate   the view
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    // Get the {@link Word} object located at this position in the   list
    Grade currentGrade = getItem(position);


    TextView nameTextView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    nameTextView.setText(currentGrade.getName());


    TextView classNameTextView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.className);
    classNameTextView.setText(currentGrade.getClassName());


    TextView gradeLetterTextView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.letterGrade);
    gradeLetterTextView.setText(currentGrade.getGradeLetter());
    return listItemView;
}
}
```

Comment: Please post the error message/Exception stack trace!

Comment: Undated the question with the error that pops up with a little more context aswell

Comment: You cannot call `setText()` with an arbitrary integer value. Your `getGradeLetter()` method returns a `char`, which is automagically converted to an `int` for you, to fit the closest method signature. You need to convert it to a `String` first; e.g., `gradeLetterTextView.setText(String.valueOf(currentGrade.getGradeLetter()));`.

Comment: Thanks alot Mike M that helped me alot. with understanding why it was crashing aswell

Answer (score -1):

Looks like R.id.name does not exist. Check your strings.xml file